# NHibernate + Paging + Ordering

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, repository, sql-order-by

I'm not quite sure of the most elegant solution for what I am trying to do.

I have a page which lists music listings, there can be thousands of these so they are paged in batches of 20, I also have 4 links at the top of the page to change the way these listings are ordered.

The sort by properties could be located on different entities such as Audio.AudioStats.NumComments or Audio.Artist.NumProfileViews.

I am using the repository pattern, and a service layer. My controllers can only access the service layer, then the service layer accesses my repositories.

I can do the paging fairly easily, i simply pass in my current page, and the page size to my data layer...but how would i safely let the user decide on the ordering of my entities.

I am using S#arp Architecture 1.5.2 if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to map the users' desires to an order by clause somehow.

Presumably you're doing something like `skip(n).take(m)` which will need an `orderby()` clause too.

Given that you have a fixed set of (known) possibilities, you can map those to an enum or similar which you then translate to the relevant `orderby()` call.

This means you don't expose the properties at the UI layer but only pass through the intent to the repository layer (as a `Sortby.ArtistProfileViews` value or whatever). What how that intent is mapped to the properties on you domain objects is isolated in your repository layer.